# Laravel - Convert mysql datetime to ago format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

**I have a posts table in the database, and the table contains datetime row.**

**I want to convert the datetime to ago format like facebook does.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `diffForHumans();` method, in the blade view file.
for example:

```
$post->datetime->diffForHumans();
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much.